# How can I subtract weekends in my list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas dataframe that is loaded with csv files along with dates in it. Lets say

```
Assigned Date 
1/15/2019

Resolved Date
1/20/2019
```

I am calculating the differance

```
df0['ResDate']  = df0['Resolved Date'].apply(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t).date())
df0['RepDate']  = df0['Assigned Date'].apply(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t).date())
df0['Woda']=df0['ResDate']-df0['RepDate']
```

I am getting the correct differance but i need to subract the weekends in this.

How do i proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.busday_count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html):

```
df0['Assigned Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['Assigned Date'])
df0['Resolved Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['Resolved Date'])

df0['Woda'] = [np.busday_count(b,a) for a, b in zip(df0['Resolved Date'],df0['Assigned Date'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` module to find the difference between two days:

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-15', '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-01-20', '%Y-%m-%d')
diff_days = (d2 - d1).days
diff_weekdays = diff_days - (diff_days // 7) * 2

print(diff_weekdays)
```

Comment: @jezrael Sorry there was a typo,edited my answer it works fine now.

Comment: So, output should be `4`, not `5` like in your answer.

Comment: Also need working in pandas DataFrame, not with scalars.